# evaluate expression given as string nasm

Tags: assembly, sum, nasm

I'm making a calculator in NASM and it is supposed to read an input, i.e. 2+3 and print the result.
What I'm doing is push everything to the stack, pop the second number(3), pop the operator(+), compare to see which operator it is and jump to the appropriate label, and then pop the first operator and do the operation.

My sum label is defined as follows

```
sum:
pop ebx
add al, bl
push eax
jmp print
```

And my print label is:

```
print:
pop eax
add ax, '0'
mov [res], ax
mov eax,4            
mov ebx,1  
mov ecx, res
mov edx, 2
int 80h 
jmp final
```

But instead of printing the result, it's printing something weird like '1O'.

What i've tried:
Before the sum label i've tried:

```
    pop eax 
    cmp byte[eax], '3'     
    je print2
    pop edx 
    pop ebx
    cmp byte[ebx], '2'   
    je print2
```

where edx is the operator, '+'
and eax was supposed to be number 3, and ebx 2, and the jump works fine.

I have tried using:

```
mov eax, 2
mov ebx, 3
mov edx, '+' ;edx is the operator
push eax
push ebx
```

and putting
    sub al,'0'

```
sub bl,'0'
```

in sum label to see if my problem was in another part of the code, but this works fine.

Any idea on what is going wrong?

Comment: Terminology: you want to "evaluate" an expression like `2+3`.   "Solve" isn't appropriate unless it's an equation like `2 + x = -3`.

Comment: This is not a [mcve].   `pop ebx` / `add al, bl`/ `push eax` could be correct if the high bytes of EAX were already zero, or if you only care about the low byte of what you push.  And if you've taken care of ASCII -> integer conversion already.  **Use a debugger to see what values are in registers when, as you single-step.**

Comment: I don't think that using machine stack SS:ESP to store elements of evaluated expression is a good idea. Reserve a separate table instead and write macros which will "push" and "pop" elements, select the operator element with highest priority and calculate elementary binary and unary operations. It will be easier to understand and debug.